# Face maps of simplicial replacement of diagrams

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to wrap my head around the construction of the simplicial replacement of a diagram, e.g. following Rodríguez-González (Realizable Homotopy Colimits, 1.5, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0646.pdf):

Given a category $\mathcal{D}$ with coproducts and an index category $I$, denote the functor category from $I$ to $\mathcal{D}$ by $\mathcal{D}^I$. The simplicial replacement $\amalg^I X$ of $X: I \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is the simplicial object given in degree $n$ by:
$$\amalg_n^I X = \coprod_{(i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)\in N_n(I)} X(i_0),$$
with the coproduct indexed by the simplicial nerve of $I$. The face maps $d_k$ of this simplicial object are defined as follows (denote with $d_k^I$ the face maps of the nerve $N(I)$). For $0 < k\leq n$, $d_k : \amalg_n^I X \rightarrow \amalg_{n-1}^I X$ maps the term $X(i_0)$ indexed by $(i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)$ to the term $X(i_0)$ indexed by $d_k^I((i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)) \in N_{n-1}(I)$, while $d_0$ sends this term via $X(i_0 \rightarrow i_1)$ to the term $X(i_1)$ indexed by $d_0^I((i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)) = (i_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n) \in N_{n-1}(I)$.

**My question** is related to these face maps. In general, we should have several different simplices $(i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n) \in N_n(I)$ for which $d_0^I((i_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)) \in N_{n-1}(I)$ coincides (e.g. by having different entries $i_0$ or different maps $i_0 \rightarrow i_1$). In my (mis-)understanding, all the terms $X(i_0)$ indexed by these simplices are mapped by $d_0$ to the same entry indexed by $(i_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow i_n)$, hence the images of all the terms $X(i_0)$ have to be "cramped" into the same entry. I would be happy about either an explanation on how this looks, or about a clarification about where in the above I am getting something wrong.

Maybe to clarify my question with a simple example: let $I$ be the category $\{0 \rightarrow 1\}$, $\mathcal{D}$ the category of groups, $X \in \mathcal{D}^I$. Is
$$d_0 : X(0)\oplus X(0) \oplus X(1) \rightarrow X(0) \oplus X(1)$$
then mapping the $X(0)$-term indexed by $0 \rightarrow 1$ via $X(0 \rightarrow 1)$ and $X(1)$ (indexed by $1\rightarrow 1$) via the identity both to the $X(1)$-term? (and if so, how is this map looking like?)

Comment: What is your actual question? It seems to me you have the correct definition. Why do you think it's wrong? Face maps do not need to be injective. (They almost never are.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I can't figure out how the "cramping" of several entries into one entry of the coproduct is defined. Sticking to the above example, if $a, b \in X(0)$ and $c \in X(1)$, then $d_0(a,b,c) = (a, ?)$, what is "?"? Is it somehow made up of b and c (and maybe the morphism between X(0) and X(1))?

Comment: You write $\oplus$, so I suppose you are working with abelian groups of some kind. Then the answer is that you take the sum.

Comment: Ah, and in general I use the unique map out of the coproduct?

Comment: In general, you do not need to worry about "mixed" elements of a coproduct. The universal property of coproducts lets you define a morphism just by defining it on the "pure" elements.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, that is where I was confusing myself initially!